# Temperature as amount of heat energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Freeman Dyson in his 1954 article on Scientific american, "What is Heat?", gave a definition of temperature in terms of heat energy required to increase the entropy by one unit.

In his narrative, he said the "...we have here implied a definition of temperature". Clearly in my view he is trying to connect temperature and entropy from the argument that when temperature decreases, energy decreases rapidly than disorder. I am not able to see the connection from his argument please elaborate the connection from his argument. As this definition is important to understand negative temperature I want to fully understand his derivation.

N.B. His first sentence of the article "Heat is disordered energy".

[image]

Comment: This is not a derivation, it's essentially a qualitative summary of the statistical mechanics definition of temperature, $T=(\partial U/\partial S)_{V,N}$. I suggest you start with the mathematical derivation.

Comment: But qualitative definition has some explanation so could you please explain?

Comment: The quote is pretty clear to me; can you point to a specific line or concept that is unclear to you?

Comment: How did he say "...here implied a definition of temperature:.." from where did he imply? Just because he stated lowering temperature increases disorder how did he assume for us to know temperature would be the amount of heat energy to increase the entropy by one unit. That's my question

Comment: Because, when this thing we call 'temperature' is high, more energy is required per unit rise of entropy (i.e. $\partial U/\partial S$), whereas at low 'temperature', less energy is required per unit rise of entropy. So 'temperature' is, at the very least, bijective with $\partial U/\partial S$.

Comment: Now it's getting clear. Can you suggest some more references I can look up?